# Kadison's Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a C*-algebra and $\omega$ a positive linear functional.

Is there a simple proof for Kadison's inequality:
$$|\omega(A)|^2\leq\|\omega\|\cdot\omega(A^*A)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your inequality only is true if $\omega$ is contractive, otherwise it is missing a $\|\omega\|$ on the right-hand-side.

The canonical (and nice) proof uses $2$-positivity. But one can prove it exactly like Cauchy-Schwarz: for $A,B\in \mathcal A$ and $t\in\mathbb C$, 
$$
0\leq\omega((B+tA)^*(B+tA))=|t|^2\omega(A^*A)+2\,\text{Re}\,t\omega(B^*A)+\omega(B^*B).
$$
This in particular occurs for all $t$ of the form $t=re^{i\theta}$ where $e^{i\theta}\omega(B^*A)=|\omega(B^*A)|$. So we have$$
0\leq r^2\omega(A^*A)+2\,r\,|\omega(B^*A)|+\omega(B^*B),
$$
for all $r\in\mathbb R$. This can only happen if 
$$
|\omega(B^*A)|^2\leq \omega(A^*A)\omega(B^*B).
$$
If $\mathcal A$ is unital, we can take $B=I$ and we get Kadison's inequality:
$$
|\omega(A)|^2\leq \omega(A^*A)\,\omega(I)=\|\omega\|\,\omega(A^*A).
$$
If $\mathcal A$ is not unital, we can use an approximation of the unit to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be unital and $\omega$ be a state. Then
 $$ 0 \leq \omega(|a - \omega(a){\bf 1}_\mathcal{A}|^2) = \omega(a^*a - a\omega(a^*) - a^* \omega(a) + |\omega(a)|^2{\bf 1}_\mathcal{A}) = \omega(a^*a) - |\omega(a)|^2. $$

Comment: Love this argument. But, for anyone who is reading this, the issue it has is that it doesn't work in general for positive linear functionals. Because it uses that $\omega$ is unital, and the proof that a normalized positive linear functional is unital usually requires Cauchy-Schwarz. And if one has Cauchy-Schwarz, there is no need for this argument.