# Restriction of state on unitisation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra with unitisation $\widetilde{A}$. Assume $\omega$ is a state on $\widetilde{A}$ such that $\omega(A)\ne 0$. Is it true that $\omega\vert_A$ is a state on $A$?

I can show that $\omega\vert_A$ is positive and satisfies $\|\omega\vert_A\|\le \|\omega\|=1$ but I don't see the other inequality.  I tried playing with an approximate unit but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. Consider for instance $A=c_0$, and $\omega$ be given by
$$
\omega(x,\lambda)=\tfrac{x_1}2+\lambda.
$$
This is a state, but $\|\omega|_A\|=\tfrac12$. One can easily see this, by thinking of $c_0+\mathbb C1$ as multiplication operators on $\ell^2$. Then
$$
\omega(x,\lambda)=\tfrac12\,\big[\langle (x,\lambda)e_1,e_1\rangle+\langle (x,\lambda)e_2,e_2\rangle\big],
$$
a convex combination of states.

More generally, any $\varphi\in A^*_+$ with $\|\varphi\|\leq1$ admits a extension to a state in $\tilde A$. Indeed, we define
$$
\tilde\varphi(a,\lambda)=\varphi(a)+\lambda. 
$$
This is obviously linear and unital, so it is enough to show that it is positive. For this,
\begin{align}
\big|\tilde\varphi\big((a,\lambda)^*(a,\lambda)\big)\big|
&=\varphi(a^*a+2\operatorname{Re}\overline\lambda a)+|\lambda|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\varphi(a^*a)+2\operatorname{Re}\overline\lambda\,\varphi(a)+|\lambda|^2\\[0.3cm]
&\geq|\varphi(a)|^2+2\operatorname{Re}\overline\lambda\,\varphi(a)+|\lambda|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=|\varphi(a)+\lambda|^2\geq0. 
\end{align}
The key inequality is [Kadison's Schwarz inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851838/kadisons-inequality), that together with $\|\varphi\|\leq1$ gives us  $$|\varphi(a)|^2\leq\|\varphi\|\,\varphi(a^*a)\leq\varphi(a^*a).$$

Comment: Thanks again! This question was inspired by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350913/jordan-decomposition-in-takesaki-theorem-iii-2-2-1

Comment: Yeah, it's not related to this. I have just answered it.